# Merge [resolution] into [something-resolution]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merge

This was a mistake. Resolution should have never been the main tag for all screen/display/monitor resolution issues. This is more evident when you get exactly 4 tags for all these issues, created by people that couldn't find the correct tag, or that the tag they found didn't make sense:

- [screen-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution)
- [monitor-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/monitor-resolution)
- [display-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/display-resolution)
- [resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution)

[resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution) name isn't self descriptive. Resolution of *what*? World hunger? This should be named as any of the other three tags instead. I'm lending towards [display-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/display-resolution) as main tag.

Comment: Yes, I agree, display-resolution sounds like a good idea.

Comment: To me, screen-resolution means the same as monitor-resolution and is hardware dependent. While display resolution would cover the viewing port of the display regardless of the number of screens. The resolution tag in and of itself I would agree is rather pointless for the reasons you state.

Comment: @Seth [tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 4):

I prefer [screen-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) for reasons related to how multihead works nowadays.

X11, the protocol underlying graphics in Ubuntu until it switches to Mir, defines a "screen" as a single surface that has a resolution and a "display" as the set of screens managed by an X server. (See ["multihead" in another distro's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/multihead).) Thus my netbook has one "display" that consists of two "screens": the internal one (whose "resolution" is 1024x600) and the VGA output (1024x768). If the screens are side-by-side, the display might not even be rectangular. The only relevant meaning for "display resolution" that I can think of is the size of a screenshot covering all the screens that make a display, or possibly with pre-xrandr multihead (Xinerama) that combined all plugged-in monitors into a single X11 screen.

So I'd assume that most should be retagged to either [screen-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) or [xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xrandr).

Comment: The problem is that we also have a screen tag for GNU screen.